# How to fill an input field using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for E2E test, and I am now trying to fill an input field with the code below:

```
await page.type('#email', 'test@example.com');
```

It worked, but I found the email address was typed into the field one character by one character as if a real human being was typing.

Is it possible to fill the input field with the email address all at one time?

Comment: The slow typing is actually (usually) a good thing, because it generates trusted events, triggers change handlers and is less prone to detection. The idea is to emulate a human typing into the field. Why do you want to fill it all in at one time?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Just set value of input like this:

```js
await page.$eval('#email', el => el.value = 'test@example.com');
```

Here is an example of using it on Wikipedia:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    await page.waitForSelector('input[name=search]');

    // await page.type('input[name=search]', 'Adenosine triphosphate');
    await page.$eval('input[name=search]', el => el.value = 'Adenosine triphosphate');

    await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitForSelector('#mw-content-text');
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const anchor = document.querySelector('#mw-content-text');
        return anchor.textContent;
    });
    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasted a bunch of time trying to get the 'type' method to work on a login. It looked like it worked, but the login always failed.

Comment: btw. waitFor method is deprecated

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also, there are simpler ways to do this using page.type(). See my answer below

Comment: Setting `el.value =` doesn't fire change handlers so this won't work on all input fields.

Answer (score 119):

another way doing

```
await page.focus('#email')
await page.keyboard.type('test54')
```

Comment: This worked. The thing is, in some forms, there is a trigger on keypress that does something. If you just set the input field value, this trigger is not run and the form submit does not work correctly.

Comment: this is a better solution. specially on react webpages because there are usually states attached to the input fields will will not be set with just setting the value.

Answer (score 94):

To extend the accepted answer above, you can use $eval with locally scoped variables too,

```
const myLocalValue = 'Adenosine triphosphate';    
await page.$eval('input[name=search]', (el, value) => el.value = value, myLocalValue);
```

This will take 'myLocalValue' from the local scope, and pass it into the browser scope as 'value'

Comment: Hello, dear Andrew! Could you please point me to the source where I can read more about this syntax?

Comment: Hi Mrrobot, it's been a while since I've looked at this and can't really remember where I got it from.  A quick look at the docs shows the prototype expected for this and the optional '...args'.  None of the examples show it that clearly but it is documented [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1).

Comment: This is super useful. I was totally confused why simply changing the string value to a local variable didn't work. Great extension and super helpful.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, static values are little to no use

Answer (score 8):

The selected answer didn't work for me in the latest version of Puppeteer(10.x). Instead what worked for me were the following commands.

```
test('should login', async () => {
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setDefaultTimeout(6000);
await page.goto('https://www.saucedemo.com/');
await page.waitForSelector('#user-name');
await page.type('#user-name', 'standard_user');
await page.type('#password', 'secret_sauce');
await page.click('#login-button');
await page.waitForSelector('#contents_wrapper');});
```

Answer (score 7):

#### page.evaluate()

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to assign the email string to the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) attribute of the element:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const email = document.querySelector('#email');
  email.value = 'test@example.com';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Puppeteer Sharp**, the syntax is a little different, and there are 2 ways to do it, but one is better than the other.  Here is a full example:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

    await using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true, Product = Product.Chrome }))
    await using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            await page.GoToAsync(urlString);
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#btnSubmit");

            await ReplaceText(page, "#inputUsernameId", usernameString);
            await ReplaceText(page, "#inputPasswordId", passwordString);

            await page.ClickAsync("#btnSubmit");
            await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();  // Optional, if the page is changing          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            // Handle me / Log me
            throw;
        }
    }
}

private static async Task ReplaceText(Page page, string selector, string replacementValue)
{
    await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(selector).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync($"document.querySelector(\"{selector}\").value = \"{replacementValue}\"").ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Alternative older method below (not as reliable with async, but works):
    // await ele.FocusAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    //
    // await page.Keyboard.DownAsync("Control").ConfigureAwait(false);
    // await ele.PressAsync("A").ConfigureAwait(false);
    // await page.Keyboard.UpAsync("Control").ConfigureAwait(false);
    // await ele.PressAsync("Backspace").ConfigureAwait(false);
    //    
    // await ele.TypeAsync(replacementText).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // await ele.PressAsync("Tab").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Page.$()

You can just get Element Handler using **page.$()** and then type your email using **type()** property of the Handler

```
const input = await page.$('#email')
await input?.type('test@example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await page.focus(".email"); //class name
await page.keyboard.type("email"); 
await page.focus(".password"); //class name
await page.keyboard.type("password");
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector(".submit").click();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer already supports `page.fill` in their last versions.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/10220/files